# React Subcomponent (Typescript) doesn't preserve state until rendered for a third time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo

I have an external component with a render method like this:

```js
    render()
    : JSX.Element 
    {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <QueryGetCustomersPaginated
                    query={Q_GET_CUSTOMERS}
                    variables={{ limit: this.props.limit, offset: this.state.offset }}
                    pollInterval={1000}
                    onCompleted={()=>console.log('Data Loading Completed!')}
                >
                    {({ loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling }) =>
                    {
                        if (loading)
                        {
                            return "Loading..."
                        }
                        if (error)
                        {
                            return `Error: ${error.message}`
                        }
                        if (data)
                        {
                            // Pass Data to Private Properties
                            this.customers    = data.getCustomers.customers
                            this.totalRecords = data.getCustomers.metadata.totalRecords

                            // Build UI
                            return (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {/* PAGE TITLE */}
                                    <h2 className="text-center mb-3">Lista de Clientes</h2>

                                    {/* Customer List */}
                                    <ul className="list-group">
                                        {
                                            this.customers.map(customer => (
                                                <CustomerItem customer={(customer as Customer)} key={customer.id} />
                                            ))
                                        }
                                    </ul>

                                    {/* Pagination */}
                                    <Paginator
                                        maxRangeSize={3}
                                        pageSize={this.props.limit}
                                        totalRecords={this.totalRecords}
                                        currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
                                        onPageChange={(newOffset: number, newPage: number) => this.setPageFor(newOffset, newPage)}
                                    />                                    

                                </React.Fragment>
                            )
                        }
                    }}
                </QueryGetCustomersPaginated>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

I also have an eventhandler for the subcomponent (Paginator) `onPageChanged` like this:

```js
    private setPageFor(offset: number, page: number)
    {
        this.setState({
            offset      : offset,
            currentPage : page
        })
    }
```

and finally the subcomponent looks like this:

```js
import React, { SyntheticEvent }            from 'react'

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Component Class
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
export class Paginator extends 
    React.PureComponent<IPaginatorProps, IPaginatorState>
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor(props: IPaginatorProps)
    {
        // Calls Super
        super(props)

        // Initialize State
        this.state = {
            initialPageInRange  : 1,
            currentPage         : 1
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public render(): JSX.Element
    {
        return (
            <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3">
                <nav>
                    <ul className="pagination">

                        {this.renderPageItems()}

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>   
        )
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private renderPageItems(): JSX.Element[]
    {
        // Return Value
        const items: JSX.Element[] = []

        for (let iCounter: number = 0; iCounter < this.getMaxPossibleRange(); iCounter++)
        {
            items.push(
                // className won't be set until third time a link is clicked..
                <li key={iCounter} className={(**this.state.currentPage** === (this.state.initialPageInRange + iCounter)) ?
                    'page-item active' : 'page-item'}>

                    <a className="page-link"
                        href="#"
                        onClick={(e: SyntheticEvent) => this.goToPage(this.state.initialPageInRange + iCounter, e)}
                    >
                        {this.state.initialPageInRange + iCounter}
                    </a>
                </li>
            )
        }

        return items
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private goToPage(page: number, e: SyntheticEvent)
    {
        e.preventDefault()

        const newOffset: number = this.getOffset(page)
        const newPage: number = this.getCurrentPage(newOffset)

        this.setState({
            currentPage: newPage
        })

        this.props.onPageChange(newOffset, newPage)
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private getOffset(currentPage: number): number
    {
        return ((currentPage - 1) * this.props.pageSize)
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private getCurrentPage(offset: number): number
    {
        return ((Math.ceil(offset / this.props.pageSize)) + 1)
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private getTotalPages(): number
    {
        return (Math.ceil(this.props.totalRecords / this.props.pageSize))
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private getMaxPossibleRange(): number
    {
        return (this.props.maxRangeSize <= this.getTotalPages()) ? 
                    this.props.maxRangeSize : this.getTotalPages()
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Component Interfaces
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IPaginatorProps
{
    maxRangeSize        : number  // 3
    pageSize            : number  // 3              
    totalRecords        : number  // 19
    currentPage         : number  // 1
    onPageChange        : (newOffset: number, newPage: number) => void
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
interface IPaginatorState
{
    initialPageInRange  : number
    currentPage         : number
}
```

As you can see, we have a main component that issues an Apollo Query with an offset parameter (set in state) that is updated every time setPageFor(offset) is called as it updates the state and re-renders the component.

Now, in the subcomponent I have two ways of getting the currentPage value, one is by using the props passed from the parent component (customers in this case), and the other is to use the component's state to set an initial value of 1 and update the state on every click in any page link.

The page link when clicked calls goToPage() which sets the local state and fires the event of page changed to the caller (customers component).

The current behavior of this component is not to change the `<li>` tag className to 'active' until the third time any link is pressed.

I have tried using `shouldComponentUpdate()`and extending React.PureComponent, I have even tried setting timeouts (I never wrote this...) to test if this worked but somehow the result is always the same.

Now, if I comment the line that triggers the `onPageChanged()` event in the `goToPage()` method, the subcomponent for pagination renders perfectly, but if I don't and the subcomponent is allowed to send the event to the parent, this one re-renders all the tree and it is like the subcomponent has been remounted causing its state to be deleted.

The weird part is that the third time I click on any link everything works as expected, it fails two times and works the third one.

I am totally puzzled at this point after hours of my weekend analyzing this code with the debugger.

I apologize for copying and pasting all this code but I believe it was necessary to get the picture of what I am trying to achieve here.

P.S. At this point the problem can be solved using props for passing the `currentPage`property from the customers component which is the subcomponent's (for pagination) caller.

I have been working with React for a few months now and this is the first time I get and error this weird, therefore I would really like to know why is this behavior happening and why the state is being lost the first two times the component renders. Also for the purpose of reusing the component, I believe it is better to keep these two variables in the state. Any thoughts from anyone who knows React better will be greatly appreciated, or is it the Apollo library the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your problem? Write in one sentence

Comment: When my subcomponent cause a render in my main component, my subcomponent can't set its state for the first two event occurrences. I have edited the code to show where the problem is (subcomponent renderPageItems() method)

Comment: you're already passing `currentPage` but not used for state init, you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps()`